# Using joins in complex queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have three tables customer_cars, bookings, and replaced_parts ad below:

```
CREATE TABLE customer_cars(
pk_car_id        NUMBER(11) NOT NULL,
car_plate_number VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE bookings(
pk_booking_id        NUMBER(11),
fk_car_id            NUMBER(11),
);

CREATE TABLE replaced_parts(
pk_parts_id          VARCHAR2(25),
fk_booking_id        NUMBER(11),
replaced_parts       parts_varray_type
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE parts_type AS OBJECT (
name                VARCHAR2(25),
price               NUMBER(10),

);
/

CREATE TYPE parts_varray_type AS 
VARRAY(40) OF parts_type;
/
```

I am trying to get parts name from parts_varray_type of a car. All i have is car_plate_number. Using this plate number i want to find pk_car_id in customer_cars and then that pk_car_if id should match with fk_car_id in bookings to find bookings_id. Then the found booking id should match with fk_booking_id in replaced_parts to get the parts_name.

```
INSERT INTO customer_cars (pk_car_id, car_plate_number)
VALUES(200000,'5651L');

INSERT INTO bookings(pk_booking_id, fk_car_id)
VALUES(700000,200000);

INSERT INTO replaced_parts (pk_parts_id, fk_booking_id, replaced_parts)
VALUES(700000,600000,
parts_varray_type(
parts_type('CLUTCH', 2000)));
```

Above is the insert statements. Now using plate number '5651L' i want to display clutch , 2000 from parts parray type.
Something like:
SELECT..
FROM..(Usings joins or any other methods)
WHERE pk_car_id = '5651L';

It should display name and price from parts varray type.

Comment: Give insert statements as well and your expected output based on that.

Comment: @Utsav i have update insert statements above.

Comment: your fk_booking_id is `600000`, but pk_booking_id is `700000`. On what basis will you join these two?

Comment: @Utsav sorry my mistake. fk_booking_id is 700000